# I tried using AppiumDriver.tap() with parameters but when it execute it throws server side error

Tags: appium

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.performTouchAction(AppiumDriver.java:297)
    at io.appium.java_client.MultiTouchAction.perform(MultiTouchAction.java:74)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.tap(AppiumDriver.java:338)
    at allpages.General.swipeLeft(General.java:44)
    at test.testappandroid.eVerify(testappandroid.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

Comment: What paramaters are you passing? Can you paste the whole command in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `adb devices` into the console, is the device listed.

For anymore help please can you post your testng.xml, your test script and you grid configurations (if you are using selenium grid).

It seems like you are experiencing [this](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4644) issue

The developers recommend:

- Make sure you are in a native view
- Use `mobile: tap` which uses the `click()` method

If none of this helps it seems as if this is an open bug, keep and eye on the issue thread linked above and to get around this problem try to use the `click` method instead of `tap`.

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: yes device is listed.     at appium is printing  "  info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":13,"value":"Failed to execute touch event"}
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"Failed to execute touch event"},"sessionId":"6797a904-51e0-442c-8c3d-5bbd98b3526a"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/6797a904-51e0-442c-8c3d-5bbd98b3526a/touch/perform 500 17.207 ms - 198 
"

Comment: are you testing a native app, hybrid app or website? Is it a real device or a simulator?

Comment: //// this the the peace of code which is causing error when it get execute at "driver.tap() " .                                                                                             public void swipeLeft()
{

 driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
System.out.println(size);
System.out.println(driver.getContext());
int x =(size.width - 5);
System.out.println("width =" +x);
int y =(size.height/2);
System.out.println("height = " + y);
driver.tap(1, x, y, 1000);
System.out.println("tapped");
 
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for my problem.
The error for me is because i missed to use "@Test" annotation in my code where i was using swipe function.

thanks